# Grab value of SELECT'ed value Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, return-value

```
$this->db->select('secretsalt,session_id'); 
$getSaltAndSessionIDFromDb = $this->db->get_where('Client', array('email' =>$ClientEmail)); // generated via registration
    $result = $getSaltAndSessionIDFromDb->result_array();
    $saltFromDb = $result[0]['secretsalt'];
    $saltedPasswordToVerify = $ClientPassword.$saltFromDb; // combine inputted pass + salt from the db
$isValidUser = $this->db->get_where('Client',array('email'=>$ClientEmail,'pass'=>$saltedPasswordToVerify)); // compare inputted pass + salt vs db entry.


// If [1] row found, login
if($isValidUser->num_rows() == 1 ){
    // set the "Logged in" vars:
    $loggedInValue = 1;
    $this->db->set('loggedIn',$loggedInValue);  // Set valid row loggedIn value = 1.
    // Validate using the below model (loginfunctionmodel) that there is:
        // 1. valid session_id
        // 2. loggedIn=1
    $this->load->model('pages/loginfunctionmodel');
    $this->loginfunctionmodel->check_if_loggedin();
}
else{
    // nothing at the moment
}
```

I want to get the value of `secretsalt` and use it in the above code where `{{HERE}}` is listed. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($getSaltAndSessionIDFromDb->num_rows() ==1)
    $result = $getSaltAndSessionIDFromDb->result_array();
    $salt = $result[0]['secretsalt'];
$saltedPasswordToVerify = $ClientPassword.$salt;
```

That should work

Comment: drop that in right where I have it below the get where line. That is why I included the last line so you'd see where it goes

Comment: Can you let me know how this looks ? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rs = $this->db->select('secretsalt,session_id')->from('tablename')->get();
$result = $rs->result_object();
```

Then use the result.

```
$saltedPasswordToVerify = $ClientPassword.$result->secretsalt;
```

If I have understood your question, that should work.

Comment: But, this is choosing both the session_id and secretsalt. I just want the ClientPassword.secretsalt   how do I do that?

Comment: Okay then assign $saltFromDb = $result->secretsalt; and use $saltFromDb but I dont see what difference that makes.